# NSIS scripting file error while extracting a zip file

Tags: nsis

When I am using the following NSIS script:

```
ZipDLL::extractall "C:\Users\sid008\Desktop\NSISTutorials.zip" "F:\nist" "<ALL>"
```

then I am getting the below error:

```
!define: "MUI_INSERT_NSISCONF"=""

Changing directory to: "C:\Users\sid008\Desktop"

Processing script file: "C:\Users\sid008\Desktop\Ext1.nsi" (ACP)Error: Can't add entry, no section or function is open!
Error in script "C:\Users\sid008\Desktop\Ext1.nsi" on line 1 -- aborting creation process
```

Any ideas on what goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says: You need to use this line inside Function or Section.

The correct usage:

```
Section "Section name"
   ZipDLL::extractall "C:\Users\sid008\Desktop\NSISTutorials.zip" "F:\nist" "<ALL>"
SectionEnd

Function Func
   ZipDLL::extractall "C:\Users\sid008\Desktop\NSISTutorials.zip" "F:\nist" "<ALL>"
FunctionEnd
```